# using a for loop to compare lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

The problem at hand is I have a list of lists that I need to iterate through and compare one by one.

```
def stockcheck():
    stock = open("Stock.csv", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(stock)
    stockList = []
    for row in reader:
        stockList.append(row)
```

The output from print(stockList) is:

```
[['Product', 'Current Stock', 'Reorder Level', 'Target Stock'], ['plain blankets', '5', '10', '50'], ['mugs', '15', '20', '120'], ['100m rope', '60', '15', '70'], ['burner', '90', '20', '100'], ['matches', '52', '10', '60'], ['bucket', '85', '15', '100'], ['spade', '60', '10', '65'], ['wood', '100', '10', '200'], ['sleeping bag', '50', '10', '60'], ['chair', '30', '10', '60']]
```

I've searched the basics for this but i've had no luck... I'm sure the solution is simple but it's escaping me!  Essentially I need to check whether the current stock is less than the re-order level, and if it is save it to a CSV (that part I can do no problem).

```
for item in stockList:
    if stockList[1][1] < stockList[1][2]:
        print("do the add to CSV jiggle")
```

This is as much as I can do but it doesn't iterate through...  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the `stockList` using list comprehension, maybe and then print out the results

```
[sl for sl in stockList[1:] if sl[1] < sl[2]]
```

You will get the following results:

```
[['mugs', '15', '20', '120']]
```

In case you were wondering `stockList[1:]` is to ensure that you ignore the header.

However, you must note that the values are strings that are being compared. Hence, the values are compared char by char. If you want integer comparisons then you must convert the strings to integers, assuming you are absolutely sure that `sl[1]` and `sl[2]` will always be integers - just being presented as strings. Just try doing:

```
[sl for sl in stockList[1:] if int(sl[1]) < int(sl[2])]
```

The result changes:

```
[['plain blankets', '5', '10', '50'], ['mugs', '15', '20', '120']]
```

Comment: `[sl for sl in stockList[1:] if sl[1] < sl[2]][0]` would give list

Comment: Very helpful thanks!  Wondering why i'm only getting the mugs coming back when plain blankets should also (15 is < 20 for mugs, and 5 is < 10 for the blankets)?

Comment: Could also avoid the whole `[1:]` stuff by using `next(reader, ''); stockList = list(reader)` instead... If the only purpose is to build a list of differences, then a list-comp directly over the reader would be more efficient than loading the entire lot into memory to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[1:]` to not get the header, and then make the comparation.

```
for item in stockList[1:]:
    if item[1] < item[2]:
        print item
        print("do the add to CSV jiggle")
```

Comment: `item[1] < item[2]` is comparing numbers as strings... Just in case. I mean, `'5' > '10'`

Comment: @MildCorma If the answers were successful, please accept an answer. Thanks